# Supporting Android 4.0

Tags: android, google-play

I've had a few emails about my app not being supported on Android 4.0 devices (The market states that this app is not supported) and users are not able to download it.

What are the steps involved to ensure an app is compatible in Android 4.0? My manifest file states that the minimum SDK version is set to 8.

Comment: Is it not possible to download the app on all ICS devices or only on the Galaxy Nexus? You should be able to see all filtering that is applied to devices in the market console. Post the corresponding parts of your app here to let us better understand what is happening(You should find it at the end of your app description).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to adding

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

In your manifest, you'll also have to change the `android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"`  in your manifest.
I hope you have made changes in the design of your app and made it compatible with ICS. You might also want to include the `android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"` in the `<supports-screen>` tag of the manifest, if you haven't already done that.

Answer (score 0):

Define targetSdkVersion as 14 and minSdkVersion as 8.